# Is there any way to render ejs template to ajax call?

Tags: jquery, node.js, ajax, bootstrap-modal, ejs

how can I render an EJS file or EJS code in ajax call. Below is code what I am trying to do. Here when a button is clicked, the respective button id is sent to server and there it is used to search data in mongodb. The data that I expected is getting but dont know how to render it. take a look at the code :

```
 view_id = $(this).attr('id');
    alert(view_id);
    var data = {"id":view_id};
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        data: JSON.stringify(data),
        contentType: "application/json",
        dataType:'json',
        url: '/transaction',                      
        success: function(data) {
                 //render template here??

            alert(JSON.stringify(data));                          
        },
        error: function(error) {
            alert(JSON.stringify(error));
         }
    });
    $('#dataModal').modal('show');

})
```

I am getting data from node.js method

```
router.post('/transaction', function(req,res){
console.log('got request');
var id = req.body.id;
console.log(id);
transaction.find({"_id":  id   }, function(err, result){
    if(err) console.log(err);
    res.json(result);
}); });
```

And here is my html Modal which has ejs.

```
<div id="dataModal" class="modal fade">  
                <div class="modal-dialog">  
                    <div class="modal-content">
                          <div class="modal-header">  
                               <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>  
                               <h4 class="modal-title">Complete Details</h4>  
                       </div>
                          <div class="modal-body" id="view_detail"> 
                          <table id="datatable" class="table table-striped table-bordered bulk_action">
                          <thead>
                            <tr>
                              <th>Details</th>
                              <th>Data</th>
                            </tr>
                          </thead>
                          <tbody>
                            <tr>
                        <% for(i=0;i<data.length;i++){%>
                              <td><%= data[i].name %></td>
                              <td><%= data[i].phone %></td>
                            </tr>
                            <% } %>
                          </tbody>
                        </table> 
                    </div> 
                          <div class="modal-footer">  
                               <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>  
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          </div>
```

Any answers or suggestions are appreciated 
..thank you

Comment: Possible duplicate, https://stackoverflow.com/a/45509794/2520628

Comment: Since you're using jQuery, why not set id's and target the dom elements to update the text/html?